# fundamental theorem of abelian groups ? Herstein

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

[image]I was reading Fundamental theorem of abelian groups in Herstein Second Edition
(pg 110), it was mentioned $b_2^{p^{n_2}} \in A_1$ and is the first power of $b_2$ to fall in $A_1.$ I was not able follow this, could someone suggest why it happens so ?

3rd paragraph, 7th line

Comment: Unfortunately, many of us don't have easy access to the book you mention. It may aid in getting an answer if you copy the relevant passage (or take a picture of it if you're less comfortable with Mathjax).

Answer (score 1):

The element $b_2$ is such that its image $\overline{b_2}=b_2+A_1$ in $G/A_1$ has maximal order $p^{n_2}$ i.e. none of the elements in $G/A_1$ has order more than $p^{n_2}$. So $(\overline{b_2})^{p^{n_2}}=A_1$ (identity element of $G/A_1$) $\Rightarrow b_2^{p^{n_2}}+A_1= A_1\Rightarrow b_2^{p^{n_2}}\in A_1$. Also, for any number $k$ with $k<p^{n_2}$, $b_2^k\notin A_1$ because otherwise $(\overline{b_2})^k=b_2^k+A_1=A_1$ which contradicts that $\overline{b_2}$ was an element of order $p^{n_2}$ in $G/A_1$.

Comment: $b_2 + A_1$ has maximal order means, all elements in $G/A_1$ has order less than $p^{n_2}.$

Comment: Yes! corrected.

Comment: How come $b_2 ^{p_{n1}} = e$

Comment: $(\overline{b_2})^{p^{n_2}}=e$ in $G/A_1$, not $b_2 ^{p_{n1}} = e$.

Comment: ya, that's okie. I'm asking another doubt which comes in the 9th line, which says $b_2^{p_{n_1}}=e$

Comment: Oh I see now! well, $a_1$ has the highest order $p^{n_1}$ among elements in $G$. So $b_2$ has order $\leq p^{n_1}$ and therefore $b_2^{p^{n_1}}=e$.

Comment: sorry yaar. $b_2 \cdots b_2 p^{n_1}$ times, but it becomes identity with less than  $p^{n_1},$ so remaining powers of $b_2$ will be there. i.e $e \cdot b_2^{p^{n_1 - n_2}} $ which is not a identity all the time.

Comment: But we are working on a group $G$ of order $p^n$; so every element of $G$ has order of the form $p^k$. If $p^m$ is the order of $b_2$, then $p^m|p^{n_1}$ and so $p^{n_1}=cp^m$ for some integer $c>0$. Therefore $b_2^{p^{n_1}}=b_2^{p^mc}=e^c=e$.